# How do I evaluate this summation?

Tags: summation, tetration

I was wondering how do I solve the summation?
$$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^nja_{m,j-1}a_{m-1,j-1}$$
I found it in this link on power towers

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PowerTower.html

Comment: ??. There is a complete formula around there - what are you missing? (It's nothing to "be solved", it's a computation-recipe)

Comment: @GottfriedHelms what I'm confused about is what the terms in the summation mean.  How do I use these terms to get actual numerical values?

Comment: I would proceed with software Pari/GP to define a function `a(m,n)=if(n==0,return(1));if(m==1,return(1/n!));  ...`. Then I would practically compute a matrix "A" as `A=matrix(16,16,r,c,a(r,c))` or the like (while I'm typing here I cannot see the formula) and after that the next formula in MW shows how to compute an actual value for th powertower of height m as sum using that coefficients of `a(m,n)` which are stored in the matrix plus the other sum. (I hope I didn't confuse you even more...)

Answer (score 1):

The actual definition is

$$a_{m,n}=
\begin{cases}
1 & \text{if }n=0\\
\frac{1}{n!}& \text{if }m=1 \\
\frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^n j a_{m,n-j} a_{m-1,j-1} & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

So to construct this array you can think of $a_{m,n}$ as a function $f(m,n)$ defined recursively as

$$f(m,n)=
\begin{cases}
1 & \text{if }n=0\\
\frac{1}{n!}& \text{if }m=1 \\
\frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^n j\times f(m,n-j)\times f(m-1,j-1) & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
with $m,n\in\mathbb{N}$. Evaluating the summation simply requires you to find the values of $f(m,n)$ at $(m,n-j)$ and $(m-1,j-1)$ for every value of $j$.

Comment: Thank You!  I think understand it now.